# Datatransfer is not working properly

Tags: rigging

[image]

The vertex information was transmitted using the data transfer modifier from the body to the skirt.

I followed along after watching YouTube.

The results were different from YouTube

If I move legs, you can see a body out of a skirt.

I changed the order of the modifier, but it didn't work well.

I tried several mix modes, but it didn't work well.

[image]

This is the setting that I used

[image]

Comment: Using the Data Transfer won't garantee that you won't see the other mesh through your mesh (as they have a different topology, they won't deform exactly the same way). What you can do is just correcting the weight of the pants in Weight Paint mode, or you can hide the legs mesh with a Mask modifier

Comment: It's comfortable to use a mask modifier Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the *Data Transfer* won't garantee that you won't see the other mesh through your mesh (as they have a different topology, they won't deform exactly the same way).

What you can do is just correct the weight of the pants in *Weight Paint* mode, or you can hide the legs mesh with a *Mask* modifier. In the second case you'll need to assign the vertices that you want to hide to a vertex group, choose this vertex group in the modifier, and press on the *Invert* button (<->) on the right:

[image]